# Mongodb commandline error

Tags: mongodb

I am getting this error when i installed mongodb and trying to open mongo.exe on command line:

> MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
>   connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>   2018-02-09T21:16:15.025+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
>   2018-02-09T21:16:15.026+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
>   @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

How to resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure, your mongodb server is running and it's up on 27017 port ?

Comment: You must run the instance of mongod for the MongoDB system before running mongo.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to start mongod server before running mongo shell. mongod bind to localhost (127.0.0.1) by default.

1- Open a terminal and start the **mongod** server

```
> mongod
```

2- Start the **mongo** shell in another terminal

```
> mongo
```

Now **mongo** shell can connect to the instance of mongod on localhost on port 27017.